# Proper place for ListView listeners

Tags: android, listview, listener

I am wondering what is the proper place for ListView listeners - I currently have my activity/fragment extending interfaces like `OnItemClickListener` and then I modify the data structure and notify adapter to update the view. What is the correct way of doing that? Anonymous classes? Let the Adapter have full control over data structure and let him be the Listener as well?

Comment: I don't think you understood my question, I know perfectly how to add listeners, I want to know however where they SHOULD be located, it would be cool if someone showed an example from some big commercial app. It's a design question, not how-to.

Answer (score 0):

Okay got you sorry for that comment. I think the best place would be in `onViewCreated()`

Answer (score 0):

Ryan's answer is good but actually I think the correct answer is it depends on how you implemented your fragment.
If you're subclassing ListFragment for example, then sample code is simply:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    ...
}
```

Link @ [ListFragment onListItemClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListFragment.html#onListItemClick(android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long))